# Qt5 - QML: Button does not show up after triggered

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qbuttongroup

I am writing a project that is using `Qt5-QML`. In order to shrink the problem I prepared a small example that replicates the problem.

**1)** I have an application on a `Page1`. That carries a `Button` as shown in the below print screen below:

[image: launch]

**2)** After the user pushes the button goes on `Page2` shown below which carries different `Buttons`. Let's say `Button A` it is the user's choice:

[image: buttons]

**3)** The final screen represented by `Page1` is the correct choice, which is the the button selected

[image: correct-selection]

**The problem** I have is that after the user selects the choice on point 2) and goes back on `Page1` a `Button` should appear on `Page1` in the middle of the `Page1` that opens a dialog window, in my case a `WebEngineView` only related to that `Button`. 
Of course if the user selcts `Button 3` on `Page2`, back on `Page1` there should be another `Button` that opens another dialog related to `Button 3` and that is always a `WebEngineView`.

I can't see the `Button` and the related dialog.

**The expected** result is the print screen below:

[image]

Below the snippet of code that carries the problem:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Conn")
    property Page1 page1: Page1 {}
    property Page2 page2: Page2 {}
    Component.onCompleted: {
        page2.onButtonClicked.connect(function(buttonId, buttonName) {
            page1.mytext.text = buttonId;
            page1.mytext.text = buttonName;
            mystackview.pop();
        });
    }

// These buttons should appear only after the user selects the choices on `Page2` 
    Button {
        id: dialogA
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        text: "Open Dialog A"
    }
    Button {
        id: dialogB
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        text: "Open Dialog B"
    }
    Button {
        id: dialogC
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        text: "Open Dialog C"
    }

    StackView {
        id: mystackview
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: page1
    }
}
```

**page1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Page {
    property alias mytext: mytext
    Button {
        id: button1
        text: "Select"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        onClicked: {
            mystackview.push(page2);
        }
    }
    Text {
        id: mytext
        anchors.top: button1.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        font.bold: true
        font.pointSize: 30
    }
}
```

**page2.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Page {
    signal onButtonClicked(var buttonId, var buttonName)

    Component.onCompleted: {
        button1.clicked.connect(function() {
            onButtonClicked(1, "A");
        });
        button2.clicked.connect(function() {
            onButtonClicked(2, "B");
        });
        button3.clicked.connect(function() {
            onButtonClicked(3, "C");
        });
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mybuttons
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 5
        Button {
            id: button1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "A"
        }
        Button {
            id: button2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "B"
        }
        Button {
            id: button3
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "C"
        }
    }
```

**What I tried so far**:

1) I came across the following [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741174/qt-qml-how-to-change-only-one-feature-of-a-say-button-style) which was useful to understand the `style` of a component. And that is for this reason that I used `Component.onCompleted:` on my code. Which did a good job in triggering the buttons at `Page2`. I thought that I could use the same philosophy also for the others but they are not showing up.

2) [This source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400002/qml-listview-selected-item-highlight-on-click) was useful for me to understand the properties of a components, in particular in the example how to highlight on a click. I think this is the most close that I can find for what I am doing.

3) Digging more in what I am trying to achieve I went ahead and went through the official documentation which seems to push for the use of the property `onCurrentItemChanged` which could be a choice as triggers the `emit` properties of a signal.

**UPDATES**

The following part in the **main.qml** is used to show that once the user triggers one of the three buttons, then on `page1` it is shown the letter of the `Button` that was clicked, in fact it is possible to see it on point **3)** of the procedure.

```
Component.onCompleted: {
        page2.onButtonClicked.connect(function(buttonId, buttonName) {
            page1.mytext.text = buttonId;
            page1.mytext.text = buttonName;
            mystackview.pop();
        });
```

This is connected to the `signal` on the **page2.qml** as shown below:

```
signal onButtonClicked(var buttonId, var buttonName)
```

Why I can't see the `Button` after I go back on `Page1` of my `QML` application? 
Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: why `page1.mytext.text = buttonId;
            page1.mytext.text = buttonName;`?

Comment: I was only checking to have pushed the right button, in fact I was grabbing the id and the name of the button triggered at `page2`and show it on `page1` as a double check.

Comment: It is understood that an MRE should not have those elements since they are noise that distracts the analysis. Do not you think that introducing this type of noise is unnecessary?

Comment: What information does the "buttonId" and "buttonName" variables provide?

Comment: I think that the code of person class is unnecessary, it is only more noise since saying that *"this code works for me"*
 does not help at all.

Comment: You are right. the second example I used is unnecessary, I was trying only to explain what I was trying to do to solve the problem. I erased the second example and updated the question.

Comment: I added **updates** on the question to make it more precise

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the three `Button` objects named `dialog`N not showing up -- they're a) not actually positioned anywhere (there's no `Layout` to contain them, etc.) and b) hidden by the `StackView` anyway which fills the parent window. I don't see how you expect them to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the "Open Dialog" buttons are always hidden by the stack view anyway. If they weren't hidden by that, they'd in any case need some flag to indicate whether they should be visible or not, based on the selection made on `Page2`.

Keeping with the existing structure of your MRE, here's one way it could work. I've moved the "Open Dialog" buttons to `Page1` because that seems to make the most sense, but they could also be on some separate page, or incorporated into main.qml if there were some layout there which allowed that. Also I made a signal/slot connection from `Page1` to trigger the `Page2` load in main.qml (instead of directly trying to access objects in main.qml, which is bad practice). I also removed the text label from `Page1` to simplify the code. `Page2` code remains unchanged so I do not include it.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Conn")
    property Page1 page1: Page1 {}
    property Page2 page2: Page2 {}

    Component.onCompleted: {
        page1.selectDialog.connect(function()  {
            mystackview.push(page2);
        });

        page2.onButtonClicked.connect(function(buttonId, buttonName) {
            page1.dialogId = buttonId;
            mystackview.pop();
        });
    }

    StackView {
        id: mystackview
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: page1
    }
}
```

**Page1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Page {

    property int dialogId: -1;

    signal selectDialog()

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 5

        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "Select"
            onClicked: selectDialog()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        // These buttons should appear only after the user selects the choices on `Page2`
        Button {
            id: dialogA
            text: "Open Dialog A"
            visible: dialogId === 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Button {
            id: dialogB
            text: "Open Dialog B"
            visible: dialogId === 2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Button {
            id: dialogC
            text: "Open Dialog C"
            visible: dialogId === 3
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your time in reading the question. Your solution works and run, but unfortunately I still am not able to see the `Button Open Dialog A`  on `Page1` after I click on choice `A` on `Page2`. I don't understand if it is due to the `StackView`.

Comment: @Emanuele I added screenshots of what I see (running in qmlscene app). If you're not getting the same results then you're either not running the same code or there's some other difference I have no clue about, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy/paste problem!. It works exactly as you described. I see how you structured and corrected the example. And above all I see how the call to the dialogs should be done. The additional `signal selectDialog()` it is a great idea. Thank you very much for your help! :)